# How do I disable waiting for wpa_supplicant lease at boot?

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I've setted up wpa_supplicant, but it waits for lease at boot. When I haven't setted up a WiFi network, then I can't boot. So how do I disable waiting for wpa_supplicant lease at boot on Debian?

Comment: Vague. What OS? Are you using a network manager? Which? Are you booting with systemd or sysvinit?

Comment: I'm using the latest Debian (Jessie). But I don't know if I'm using systemd or sysvinit. I'm not using any network manager.

Answer (score 0):

Add the flag -nw to dhclient, so it doesn't wait.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the file and put it somewhere you can restore it later from if needed. This will do the trick.